# Replace latex index syntax with restructured text index syntax

Tags: regex, latex, restructuredtext, pandoc

I am converting a document from LaTeX (XeTeX) to ReStructuredText using Pandoc. The document has a large number of index entries, and Pandoc does not handle indices. The index entries are stripped out when Pandoc converts, leaving just the text of the entry. So, what I need is a way to convert the index entries to ReST syntax in the LaTeX file before Pandoc strips them out upon conversion. In my tests, this sort of works: Pandoc preserves the index entries but escapes the backticks. I can strip those out. Here's how it looks when I do it manually:

```
\index{Some index item}    # The LaTex entry
:index:`Some index item`   # Modified for ReST format (still in the LaTeX file)
:index:\`Some index item\` # Result after Pandoc conversion to ReST
```

I can replace the final escaped backticks with proper backticks in the final ReST file. What I can't seem to figure out is how to create a workable method (Regex?) for the replacements in the LaTeX file. Suggestions most welcome (including suggestions about a better way to do this whole production).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking to replace entries that match the following regular expression

```
^\\index\{([^}]*)\}
```

with

```
:index:`$1`
```

where `$1` is a reference to the regex's capture group `([^}]*)`.

You could automate this process with, for example, a shell script or do it manually in a text editor.

Note, the above regex assumes there is no `}` inside the `{}`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your Regex works perfectly. The more I dive into this, the more it seems I am still going to have to manually work on some of these index entries. For example, the Regex works for stand-alone index entries but not for inline entries (and, of course, there are several kinds of index variations, such as those with sectioning syntax, emphasis, and other things). So, at least I have a start. Thanks again.

Comment: @rosslaird. The above regex assumes that each index entry is at the beginning of a line. If that is not the case remove the leading `^`.

Comment: Yes, I did that, and captured more of the inline entries. The tricky thing now is that the standalone entries have the single term only, whereas the inline entries have the term repeated. So I now have many versions of `:index:'entry'entry`. I'm working on how to come up with a Regex to remove that second term.

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles across this, here is the regex to replace the double occurrences of the index term: `(\b`\w+)`, with the backtick as the replacement term.